# Spark on YARN - saveAsTextFile() method creating lot of empty part files

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running the Spark job on Hadoop YARN Cluster.

i am using `saveAsTextFile()` method to store the RDD to text file.

I can see more than 150 empty part files created out of 250 files.

Is there a way we can avoid this?

Comment: How many executors are you using?

Comment: @karthikmanchala : 30 executors.

Comment: So.. empty part files are randomly written by executors?

Comment: How many partitions do you have? 250?

Comment: @Hlib : Yes, i have 251 partitions..

Answer (score 2):

Each partition is written to it's own file. Empty partitions will be written as empty files.

In order to avoid writing the empty files you can either `coalesce` or `repartition` your RDD into a smaller number of partitions.

If you didn't expect to have empty partitions, it may be worth investigating why you have them.  Empty partitions can happen either due to a filtering step which removed all the elements from some partitions, or due to a bad hash function.  If the `hashCode()` for your RDD's elements doesn't distribute the elements well, it's possible to end up with an unbalanced RDD that has empty partitions.